# javafx application jar file is not running in linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, jar, executable-jar

I have created a JavaFX application in windows , I have created a jar file in windows. I need to execute the jar file in Linux command line I have set 
JAVA HOME and tried.Is it possible to run jar for javafx in linux?

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

So I just got this error [image]

**jdk version is 1.8**

Comment: Where is the class org.restlet.resource.ResourceException? Sounds like you have not configured the classpath properly.

Comment: jar works fine in windows, if configured wrongly then it wont work in windows right?

Comment: It might be set up differently. In Windows command line , do `echo %CLASSPATH%` and in Linux command line to `echo $CLASSPATH` to see what you get.

Comment: well I didn't get that clearly ..do I need to echo from specific directory?

Comment: no, any directory. I'm thinking that in Windows, the classpath was pre-configured to include the jar file containing `org.restlet.resource.ResourceException`, but it has not been set in Linux.

Comment: for restlet framework the jar file is included in project library path ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95027/discussion-between-nickj-and-james-hoffman).